# Watermark does not show in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, jpeg, watermark

I have noticed that on certain photos with watermarks, the watermark will show
in programs like *Windows Photo Viewer* and *Paint* but not in
*Windows Explorer*.

Here is an [example photo](//500px.com/photo/50197200) and [related thread](//forums.adobe.com/thread/1207858). Here is an
example of the problem as found in that thread:

> [image: example]

Does this mean that the non-watermarked image can be extracted in some cases?

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess this is more of a rendering glitch if anything.  As if a watermark can be removed that depends on how it was placed in the first place.

Comment: The thumbnail and the real image are stored seperately. I've seen many images where the thumbnail was rotated 180 degrees or was completely different from the main image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examining the given jpeg in Windows Explorer gives no watermark in the thumbnails and a watermark in the preview screen. Further examination of the .jpeg by an [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) shows (only relevant info showed):

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.39
File Name                       : 5.jpg
File Size                       : 129 kB
File Type                       : JPEG
Photoshop Thumbnail             : (Binary data 14603 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Thumbnail Offset                : 19234
Thumbnail Length                : 10749
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 10749 bytes, use -b option to extract)
```

So there is a **thumbnail embedded in the jpeg** (in the exif/meta data) which is used by Windows Explorer (and other software).

When you open this image in Paint and save it as a different file, the thumbnail itself is not in the file anymore and your Windows Explorer thumbnail shows the watermark. (See image)

**To answer the question**: Yes, **A** (not the) non-watermarked image can be extracted but will only be 14603 or 10749 bytes in size which is probably of a lot less quality than the original.

The original (5.jpg) and saved in Paint (5b.jpg):

[image: Images]

Comment: Very useful tool and information. How to extract the image without thumbnail? I did the "-b" option but only display meta in binary mode

Comment: @Kreker The -b option is to extract the metadata (or small preview image/thumbnail) as binary data (see documentation). If you want **only** the image without thumbnail, you want to **remove** the metadata. You can do that with `exiftool -all= foo.jpg`.

Comment: mmm I tryed this command but doesn't extract the photo without the  watermark. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Kreker Yes, you are misunderstanding. The big image always has a watermark. You can't remove it (that's the point). The exiftool gives you the opportunity to extract the **small** thumbnail version or remove it. But it can't remove any watermarking in the big image itself. So the only thing you can do is extract that thumbnail with -b and use that (but it will be small). According to the documentation you can do this `exiftool -b -ThumbnailImage image.jpg > thumbnail.jpg`

Comment: @Rik: Use `exiftool -a -b -W %d%f_%t%-c.%s -preview:all` to extract all types of thumbnails, there can be several.

Comment: @Rik: Thumbnail types available in ExifTool can be listed by `exiftool -list -preview:all`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search turned up this [thread](http://photo.net/digital-darkroom-forum/00N4Pb).  According to the thread, LightRoom creates small watermarks in the bottom left corner of thumbnails for Explorer. This is probably to keep the smaller thumbnail from losing fidelity.  Read the thread they talk about solutions.

Im curious, turn on show hidden/system files and then delete the `thumbs.db` file.  I wonder if Windows generates the thumbnail, that the watermark from the fullsize picture will be there.